# Intel says my cpu has vt-x but kvm-ok says it doesn't

Tags: linux, kvm-switch, android-studio, vt-x, debian-bookworm

I just installed Debian 12, downloaded Android Studio and was following this article to enable VM acceleration: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration?utm_source=android-studio&hl=pt-br#vm-linux which says:

> To use VM acceleration on Linux, your computer must also meet these
> requirements:
>
> - For Intel processors: Support for Virtualization Technology (VT-x), Intel EM64T (Intel 64) features, and Execute Disable (XD) Bit
>   functionality enabled.

I have an Intel Core i3 10100 and the specifications here https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/199283/intel-core-i310100-processor-6m-cache-up-to-4-30-ghz/specifications.html say:

> - Intel® 64: Yes
> - Execute Disable Bit: Yes
> - Intel® Virtualization Technology (VT-x): Yes
> - Intel® Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O (VT-d): Yes
> - Intel® VT-x with Extended Page Tables (EPT): Yes

But when I run

```
egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
```

I get 0 as response.

And when I run

```
sudo kvm-ok
```

I get:

```
INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
KVM acceleration can NOT be used
```

I already enabled VT-d on the UEFI, I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Even if the CPU has it, you typically have to enable the virtualization options in the BIOS.

Comment: @acejavelin sorry, I'm so dumb, I just restarted my pc after posting this to fiddle around on the UEFI and found it, the VT-x was disabled

Comment: If you have a proper answer then you should post it below. We don't want "solved" in the title because as a Question and Answer site we have a proper way of marking a question as "solved" which is by accepting an answer. Otherwise you can simply delete your question if there is no real answer.

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1425251/info-your-cpu-does-not-support-kvm-extensions-kvm-acceleration-can-not-be-used) suggests you need to enable VT-x within the BIOS.

Answer (score 2):

Even if the CPU has it, you typically have to enable the virtualization options in the BIOS.

Reboot the PC and enter the BIOS/UEFI firmware setup and check the CPU or Advanced settings, the exact location varies by firmware and manufacturer, but verify VT-x is enabled. This is sometimes just referred to as Intel Virtualization Technology, Virtualization Technology, VT-x, or SVM, depending on the BIOS/UEFI firmware.

Source: https://www.technewstoday.com/vt-x-is-disabled-in-the-bios/